# SqlDBtype issue with ASp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3

Hi guys I am having a problem with this code in sqldbtype I don't know why although there is nothing wrong can you help me to discover th![enter image description here][1]is problem

Sorry for attaching the picture from external link because I am new in stackoverflow and this require a reputation to attach image. best regards

http://www.iraqi-up.com/uploads/13952507661.png

```
public static int inserforum(int Title_id, string Question, string Post_name, DateTime Date_time) 
{
    int rowsAffected = 0;
    using (SqlConnection connection = ConnectionManager.GetDatabaseConnection()) 
    { 
        SqlCommand command= new SqlCommand ("inserforum", connection) ;
        command.CommandType=CommandType.StoredProcedure; 
        command.Parameters.Add("@Title_id",sqlDbType.Int).value=Title_id; 
        command.Parameters.Add("Question",sqlDbType.varChar).value=Question;
             command.Parameters.Add("Post_name",sqlDbType.varChar).value=Post_name;
             command.Parameters.Add("Date_time",sqlDbType.DateTime).value=Date_time;
        rowsAffected=command.EndExecuteNonQuery(); 
    }
    return rowsAffected; 
}}
```

Comment: that image link is broken

Comment: ok the link is fixed up

Comment: you mean removing "End" ?

Answer (score 0):

Its "SqlDbType", not "sqlDbType". C# is case sensitive, you cannot use lowercase and uppercase indiscriminately like you can in other languages.

Also, you want to use the non query method that is not a Begin or End method.

rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

Using the Begin/End versions of this are for Asynchronous executions of a query, which is useful in some cases but not many.